# How to get email from Notify Me field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

I have a Coming soon page and have a countdown to beta launch and a field where user can enter their email to be added to a mailing list for the beta launch.

How do I receive the email from the field and email myself the user's email upon submit?

Is there a third party service I can use for this? And javascript or jquery plugin?

This is the form with no javascript:

```
              <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill">Notify Me</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: When you submit the form, the form data will itself have the email field which you can extract at server end.

Comment: There's no server right now -- im just going to have the html on godaddy

Comment: You probably have a webserver that the site lives on, and that webserver probably have mail software installed, and something like PHP to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write backed code with whatever you have on server if it is PHP you could store data from form in file or send it to mail.

[Form guide with better description of your problem](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/html-email-form.html)